# Angular2 remote configuration + authentication

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application with different backend instances. Every of them has its own configuration which is available as a RESTful resource. Every resource is JWT-protected: I should add an authorisation token to an every request.

The requirement: before the application starts I need to resolve the configuration that it is available for every component / service / etc (except for the authentication module including the login page) in the application.

The problem: application has a login page which does not require this configuration, but the configuration requires the token which is received after user is successfully logged in.

The ways I think of but can't go with them due to all the limitations above:

- disabling authentication on the backend: firstly I'm not the backend owner, secondly I want a clean solution and this sounds like a workaround
- `APP_INITIALIZER`: the app should be initialised before the configuration is received because of the authentication module / login page
- `<router-outlet *ngIf="isConfigResolved">` in the `AppComponent`: login page is a part of routing; if I do so, I also block the login page

The only way I see is adding `resolve` condition to an every route (but login page of course) in the application. Although one could argue this is a proper way to do the things because every route claims the dependency, I don't really like this solution.

Are there options I am missing?